# How character arrays work in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have begun learning C on my own.  I am using Head First C.

The below program is a bit confusing to me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("Hello World!");
    puts("Enter your favorite Number:");
    char arrayOfNumbers[3];
    scanf("%2s",arrayOfNumbers);
    //printf(arrayOfNumbers);
    char s[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    printf(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is :

> Hello World!
>
> Enter your favorite Number:
>
> 1
>
> abcde1

What I don't get is, inspite of the fact that I am copying the input '1' in the array arrayOfNumbers, and then I am printing the array 's', the output contains the 1 I entered.  How is the input being copied to the array 's'?

Comment: Don't get a `1` at the end! Works fine for me! (Ah hmm BTW: `printf(s)` seriously ? And '\0' wouldn't hurt!)

Comment: `printf` expects a null-terminated string. You aren't passing it one, invoking *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am very much new to C.

Comment: It is not the same question, the just have the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `char s[]` is missing the terminating null byte `'\0'` and read past the end of the array by `printf`. So it prints the next value on the stack I suppose. Fix it like this and see

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("Hello World!");
    puts("Enter your favorite Number:");
    char arrayOfNumbers[3];
    scanf("%2s",arrayOfNumbers);
    //printf(arrayOfNumbers);
    char s[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','\0'}; // see the added '\0' byte
    printf(s);
    return 0;
}
```

the strings in C require an unprintable byte to mark the end of the string, there are many functions that expect this like `strlen` for instance, `printf` is one of them. If you are on Linux, [valgrind](http://www.google.co.ve/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvalgrind.org%2F&ei=G3eMVI78KYamNp7rgeAH&usg=AFQjCNHQlvGRULIyRUKZcCGU0LCl3BORew&sig2=csrZQ0YfdZpyXiAyw-aOHQ&bvm=bv.81828268,d.eXY) would have told you about it

Comment: Oh, the expected unprintable byte is `'\0'` or `0` they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below:
You should have a NULL terminated string in order for the printf to print the string.
Printing a string without format specifier can be dangerous. If your string has some format specifer like %d or %s then the printf() will be expecting that there will be an argument after this and it might read some value from your stack. So IMO you should use format specifier %s in order to print strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("Hello World!");
    puts("Enter your favorite Number:");
    char arrayOfNumbers[3];
    scanf("%2s",arrayOfNumbers); 
    printf("%s\n",arrayOfNumbers); /* or printf(arrayOfNumbers); */
    char s[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};
    printf("%s",s); /* or printf(s); */
    return 0;
}
```